# When does Visual Studio kill an .exe launched via "Start Without Debugging"?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm building ASP.NET web apps in VS 2017. Start Without Debugging runs the application, however I can't tell when VS decides to kill the exe. How is that managed? I'm not encountering a problem; all behavior is per documentation. Just curious.